# Lowest cost based on case sizes

Tags: php, knapsack-problem

I'm working on a shipping module for wine, and was wondering if anyone could give me a hand - basically:

The wine can be shipped in cases of 8, 12 or 15 bottles, each with its own price. The module needs to take the total number of bottles in the order, and work out which combination of cases gives the lowest price. Eg in an order of 31 bottles, the lowest price works out to 1 case of 15 and two cases of 8, (rather than 2 cases of 15 and 1 of 8, or 2 of 12 and one of 8). Currently, I have the following, which almost works, but misses a few possible combinations

```
    foreach ($rates as $case_size => $case_price) 
    {
      $price = floor($total_bottles / $case_size) * $case_price;
      $rem = $total_bottles % $case_size;
      if($rem > 12)
      {
       //needs to use another case of 15 
       $price = $price + $rates[15];
      }
      elseif($rem > 8)
      {
        //needs an extra case of 12
        $price = $price + $rates[12];
      }
      elseif($rem > 0)
      {
        //needs an extra case of 8
        $price = $price + $rates[8];
      }
      $quotes[] = $price;
    }

    return min($quotes);
```

Comment: It seems a bit redundant. If customer A bought 27 bottles and the program figured out how to box it, then you have the answer for all future customers who order 27 bottles. No need to recalculate over and over. I would use a spreaddsheet or something to find out what works best, then use an array with the options.

Comment: I see your point, but each country has its own set of rates for each case size too, so it gets a bit complex. Don't really want to have to make a spreadsheet for each country, for each possible order quantity. Surely theres a way to do this programatically

Comment: Ok, then make the lookup use number of bottles and target country as input. Shouldn't be too complicated to create a lookup table. On the other hand: Is there really a need to optimize this to the max in favor of the customer?

Comment: @RST Could go with the halfway house: do it programmatically and then cache it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your post your saying that the most price-effective system wouldn't just the one that has uses the lowest cost per bottle of the container, but also needs to be the most efficient at filling the containers.  However your algorithm is only looking at would use the fewest large boxes possible. You need an algorithm that will completely fill each case possible.

I would do something like this: Use a recursive program to find the combination that would most completely fill each case.

```
function fit_case($number, $case_size) {
     $rem = $number % $case_size;
     $next_size=magic_voodo0();
     if($rem==0) {        //if perfectly fills it you're done
           return ($number/$case_size)*$rates[$case_size];
     } else if(($rem % $next_size)/$next_size>.5) {               
     //if over 50% fills the next case add the next smaller case
           return floor($number/$case_size)*$rates[$case_size]+fit_case($rem, $next_size);
      } else {        //otherwise back off 1 of the biggest cases, and fill the rest
         return (floor($number/$case_size)-1)*$rates[$case_size]+fit_case($rem, $next_size);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This would still lead to using 2x15 and 1x8 boxes. While he stated in this case 1x15 and 2x8 boxes would be cheaper.

Comment: This wouldn't lead to the 2X15 and 1x8 boxes. The remainder would be less than 50% of the 8 case, so the algorithm would use 1 less 15 case, and would fill the rest with 8 cases. So you'd be left with 1X15 and 2X8.

Comment: You are right but I think it will use a 12 bottles box instead.

Comment: Thanks for this - not sure what you mean with the 50% thing but a recursive function like this might do the trick. I can't mark it as 'useful' as I don't have the 'reputation' sorry. The idea is to minimise cost, not really to fill the containers best - so the largest containers are the most cost effective. But theres a few cases like with 33 bottles, where a case of 8, one of 12 and one of 15 gives the cheapest price (compared to 3x12 or 2x15+1x8 or 4x8). Really frustrating as I doubt a customer will ever buy 33 bottles!

Comment: You're right, then the tolerance for the remainder being over a percentage just needs to be changed.  To 80% I think.  12/15=80% and 8/12=75% so if it has to be over 80% I think that should find the most effective combination.

Comment: The 50% thing is the next smaller case is over 50%(actually should be more around 80%) full, it will use the max number of the biggest cases. If the next smaller case is only partly filled i.e. 1 bottle it will use 1 less than the max number of the largest cases. and will try to fill the smaller cases more effectively. You may need to add something to the function for the smallest case so it'll just return rather than keep calling the function for a non-existant case because the smallest case is only partially filled.

Comment: If lowest costs is your primair goal then this may still be wrong. It will depend on the price differences between the boxes in the different countries. The 15-8-8 might not work in all countries.

Comment: It's almost completely safe to assume that the cost effectiveness will be proportional to the number of bottles per case. If this isn't the case you can simply have the next_size not be the next smallest case but the next case that's most effective.

Answer (score 0):

Different approach. Use a lookup table that has all combinations of boxes for a specific number of bottles.

- 1 bottle - 8
- ...
- 31 bottle - 15-8-8,15-15-8,8-8-8-8, and so on
- and so on

Use another lookup table for the different rates per box per country

In your function

- get table row for country prices
- get the different combinations for the number of bottles
- do a foreach loop on combinations
- save the price and combination of first loop to variables
- compare the price of the next loop with the saved value
- if it is lower, save price and combination/if not, continue
- loop through all combinations
- return lowest price/box combination